# Syntax error using CLIENT KILL USER <username> on Redis 5.9.102

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm trying to kill a Redis client by user, as per [the docs](https://redis.io/commands/client-kill), but I get a syntax error in `redis-cli`:

```
redis:6379> client kill user my_client
(error) ERR syntax error
redis:6379> info
# Server
redis_version:5.9.102
```

What's the correct syntax for this command?

Comment: Do you want to terminate an authenticated user or some client(s) show in client list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [this commit](https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/cec388f208c44c2f636da42258d14c6ba5411faa) (May 1,2020) which is commited to the `unstable` version, your syntax is correct. But it is not released to the stable versions such as  the one you used.

If you want to remove client by ip:port format then you need something like this;

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=272 addr=127.0.0.1:51374 fd=8 name= age=66 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=26 qbuf-free=32742 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
id=273 addr=127.0.0.1:51376 fd=9 name= age=19 idle=16 flags=P db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
127.0.0.1:6379> client kill 127.0.0.1:51376
OK
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's useful to know. I used killing by id instead. Perhaps the live documentation should reflect the stable version (and fix the typo in that paragraph).

Comment: @AlexDeva I opened an issue on the github about the typo yesterday. They may update it. If the answer is okay on your side, please approve it - it may help to someone else.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about forgetting to approve the answer. Thanks for reminding me.